# phpmyadmin on my server doesn't support compression

Tags: compression

phpmyadmin on my server doesn't support compression:

You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/gzip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.

I need to import a database aaa.sql.gz

How can I change the configuration and what precisely ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `phpinfo()` show zlib support enabled (i.e. `'--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'` in Configure Command output) ..?

See [Zlib Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php) from the PHP manual to install if necessary.

**Update**

phpMyAdmin is checking against `@function_exists('gzopen')` [phpmyadmin/libraries/File.class.php:660 if you happen to be using v2.11.8.1] before returning the error string you referenced - do you see any errors logged when you call `gzopen()` from a script ..?

```
<?php
  error_reporting( E_ALL );
  $fp = gzopen("/path/to/aaa.sql.gz", "r");
?>
```

Comment: Uhm, I don't have your i.e. ('--with-zlib'...) but I have zlib table and ZLib Support  enabled  is the first row